# scrapoxy - How to limit the number of instances that get created

Tags: proxy, digital-ocean, scrapoxy

I am using [this](https://scrapoxy.io/) library to setup a proxy on digital ocean and I am looking for a way to limit the number of droplets that get created in DigitalOcean so while looking at the documentation I came across [this](http://scrapoxy.readthedocs.io/en/master/advanced/understand/index.html#how-does-multi-providers-work) link which suggests that to limit the droplet I need to add `max` which I did however that does not seem to work, right now I am seeing a new droplet being created every few seconds and i want to reduce that to 2 if possible just to test things out.

This is what i have in my configuration

```
{
    "commander": {
        "password": "password"
    },
    "instance": {
        "port": 3128,
        "scaling": {
            "min": 1,
            "max": 2
        },
        "log": {
            "path": "/log"
        }
    },
    "providers": [
        {
            "type": "digitalocean",
            "token": "the-token-goes-here",
            "region": "SGP1",
            "size": "s-1vcpu-2gb",
            "sshKeyName": "ubuntu",
            "imageName": "name-of-image",
            "tags": "proxy,instance",
            "max": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

My understanding is by adding the max I should have been able to limit the droplets but I see no difference, is this the right place to add? What am i missing here[?](https://scrapoxy.io/)